# Select child element based on CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

So what I would like to do is select a `div` inside `slide_items` that is not set to `display: none`, using jQuery. How could I do that?

```
<div id="slide_items">
  <div id="slide_item_1">
    <h2>Item 1</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div id="slide_item_2" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Item 2</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div id="slide_item_3" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Item 3</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div id="slide_item_4" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Item 4</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to add a fifth answer but it seemed like overkill...

Comment: Are you after a `div` that is a direct child of `#slide_items` or any descendant `div`? If the former, use Yi Jiang's answer, otherwise, the `find()` method will be faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using the [`:visible` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```
$('#slide_items > div:visible')
```

Comment: Note that of course this is only for the `display: none` property - other CSS properties will probably require you to either use `filter` or, if you're going to reuse it often, write your own selector

Answer (score 2):

I believe this `$("#slide_items div:visible")` work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#slide_items').find('div:visible')...
```

See http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#slide_items').find('div:visible');
```